# lines() not showing in r

Tags: r, time-series

I was trying to do the forecast for time series. But the confidence interval and predicted value won't show up on the time series plot. I her posted all of my code below, although some might not be relevant to my question.

```
ap = scan("airpass.txt")
tsap = ts(ap)
log.ap = log(ap)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot.ts(ap,ylab = "airpass")
plot.ts(log.ap, ylab = "log of airpass")

n = length(log.ap) 
tt = seq(1,n) 
tt2 = tt^2
cos12 = cos(2*pi*tt/12) 
sin12 = sin(2*pi*tt/12) 
cos6 = cos(2*pi*tt/6) 
sin6 = sin(2*pi*tt/6) 
cos4 = cos(2*pi*tt/4) 
sin4 = sin(2*pi*tt/4)
rg <- lm(log.ap ~ tt + tt2 + cos12 + sin12 + cos6 + sin6 + cos4 + sin4) 
summary(rg)

plot.ts(log.ap) 
lines(fitted.values(rg),col="red")

res = residuals(rg)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot.ts(res)
acf(res, lag.max = 20, ylim = c(-1,1))

library(forecast)
ar.res = auto.arima(res,max.p=5,max.q = 0,ic="aic",allowmean = FALSE)
res.res = residuals(ar.res)



h = 5
ar.pre = predict(ar.res,h)
fy = 145:149
# trend forecast
fct = rg$coef[1]+rg$coef[2]*fy+rg$coef[2]*fy+rg$coef[3]*(fy^2)+rg$coef[4]*(cos(2*pi*fy/12))
     +rg$coef[5]*(sin(2*pi*fy/12))+rg$coef[6]*(cos(2*pi*fy/6))+rg$coef[7]*(sin(2*pi*fy/6))
# trend+ar forecast
mean = exp(fct+ar.pre$pred)
# interval
bdr = 1.96*ar.pre$se
upper = exp(fct+ar.pre$pred+bdr)
lower = exp(fct+ar.pre$pred-bdr)

plot(tsap,xlim= c(0,150))
lines(fy, c(mean), lty=1, lwd=2)
lines(fy, c(lower), lty=2, lwd=2)
lines(fy, c(upper), lty=2, lwd=2)
title("Forecasts for the time series")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just recreated the code using sampling to mimic what you obtained:

```
fy = 145:149

tsap <- tibble(x=sample(1:200,100),y=sample(1:200,100))

plot(tsap,xlim= c(0,150))
lines(fy, sample(1:200,5), lty=1, lwd=2)
lines(fy, sample(1:200,5), lty=2, lwd=2)
lines(fy, sample(1:200,5), lty=2, lwd=2)
```

I can see the lines. Perhaps your problem is in the model fitting and posterior predictions. Maybe if you share the data I can help more.

Comment: I just edited my code. I am not sure how I can share the data file.

Comment: Well there are many ways. You can plot the results of the main file on the console so I can just at least have an idea of the structure. You can also call the function summary() over it. There are many possibilities. Perhaps a link to the file ?